# Error while generating XML document

Tags: c#, xml

I am using the following C# code to create a XML file:

```
private void CreateXML()
{
    _logger.Log("Creating XML....");

    XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings
    {
        Indent = true,
        OmitXmlDeclaration = false,
        Encoding = Encoding.UTF8,
        CheckCharacters = true
    };

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Page>));

    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(_outputXMLFilePath, xmlWriterSettings))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, this._pages);
    }

    _logger.Log("XML Created");
}
```

On line `serializer.Serialize(writer, this._pages);` I am getting the following exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll
>
> Additional information: There was an error generating the XML document.

Can anyone please tell me what is the issue here?

Comment: What is `_pages`? Likely some issue in its definition with respect to XML serialisation.

Comment: Have you tried to go step-by-step through your code from within the debugger? You could also wrap your code in a `try/catch` block and print the exception message.

Comment: Try checking the InnerException of your InvalidOperationException for more detail about the root cause of the error.  The MSDN article on this has lots of detail: [Troubleshooting Common Problems with the XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302290.aspx)